# Cannot listen for UDP packets in Python- socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets, udp, client-server

I am trying to listen for UDP packets i am sending across my local network.

I have tried using https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication with no joy and many other tutorials.

I am sending this packet off a windows laptop

```
import socket
import time

Host = '192.168.1.7'
Port = 5050
Message = 'hello world'+time.asctime()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
   sock.sendto(Message(Host,Port)
   print 'sent', Message
   time.sleep(5)
```

I have used the following to try and receive the UDP packets

```
import socket

Host = '192.168.1.138'
Port = 5050

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind((Host, 5050))

while True:
    recieved = sock.recv(1024)
    print recieved
```

and

```
import socket


UDP_IP = "192.168.1.138"

UDP_PORT = 5050

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


while True:

    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes

    print "received message:", data
```

I have ran the following recieve method on localhost and works perfectly fine but as soon as i assign an ip address of a device on my Local area network i get the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/Myname/Desktop/untitled/recieve.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Myname/Desktop/untitled/recieve.py", line 12, in <module>
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tested this on 4 different devices all running python 2.7 and this is the same message i got. It was ran on a windows 7 laptop, MacBook, Kali Linux laptop, and PIXEL Raspbian on a raspberryPi

Comment: Perhaps what you want to do instead is sock.bind((None, UDP_PORT)) ?  That way you will receive incoming packets on all local network interfaces rather than only on the network interface that has IP address 192.168.1.138.

Comment: similar error raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Faiz/Desktop/untitled/recieve.py", line 12, in <module>
    sock.bind((None, UDP_PORT))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Comment: Oops, pardon me, I meant to say:  sock.bind(("", UDP_PORT))

Comment: it works!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use `socket.bind(("localhost", 80))` or `socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 80))` you will still have a “server” socket, but it will only be visible within the same machine.

You can try `socket.bind(("", 80))` to tell the socket to be reachable by any address the machine may have.